# Removing NTL Internet Provider Boxes (UK)

Tags: electrical, drywall, cables, coaxial-cable

We're doing some redecoration, have stripped wallpaper and want to replaster and paint over.

We've got one of these old NTL boxes on the wall, with the cables coming in. Are we fine to plaster these into the wall? How should we remove them?

[image: NTL Box and Wiring]

Comment: Do you own the house, and will you ever have use for the coax, EG for a satellite dish, a rooftop antenna, or a traditional cable TV service?  If your TVs and the programming you buy are all streaming all Wi-Fi, you can just snip these and forget about them.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, yes you can bury them.
All cables in walls in the UK are 'caveat emptor' - buyer [or DIYer] beware.

In case they're still connected to any other part of your ISP or telecom supply, make sure they can't be shorted by wet plaster or left touching [landline phone voltages are pretty serious, even if the cableTV line isn't]. Wrapping each separately in insulating tape ought to be fine.

However… and I've been bitten by this before - the cables & box still belong to Virgin Media, the successors to NTL [& TeleWest, Cable London & BlueYonder]. If you ever have them in to add/change/extend a Virgin installation, they'll want them back if they aid their installation [the cables not the box].
They *can* eventually be persuaded to just forget it ever existed, but it's wise to be forearmed with the knowledge.

Comment: I would be tempted to coil up the cable and leave it in some way that is accessible in case you or a future resident wishes to take Virgin service. Cutting the cable may involve a much more disruptive install to replace it in future. Maybe you can tuck it somewhere and leave some marker so the next person can find it? The actual plastic box isn’t important but it’s the cable that’s hard to reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

In the end we contacted Virgin and they came and removed it!

We currently have our internet provided by them, and so they did it free of charge in a couple of days.

However, from the other research I did it should be fine to cap the ends and put in the wall. I would have got a blank plate to put over the top to pull them out if we ever did need them again.

Thanks all!